# How to get to a new location based on an li click that has the url id as an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller

Hi I have some code like:

```
<ul>
  <li data-id="1"></li>
  <li data-id="2"></li>
  <li data-id="3"></li>
</ul>
```

In a script:

```
$('li').click(function () {

            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("View", "People", new { id = $(this).data('id')})';
        });
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that when a user clicks a list item it redirects to:

People/View/id

where id is the id attribute on the list item.

Trouble is I can't work out what is wrong with the code.

The part $(this).data('id') has a squiggly underline and says:

',' or '}' expected.

Sorry this is probably a really dumb question but I can 't corrently work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not mix server and clientside code. They do not interact with each other.

I am guessing you need to do something like this:

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("View", "People")' + "/" + $(this).data('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

The Url.Action method does not work in javascript. It's part of server-side MVC. You may generate the link directly in your MVC view such as:

```
<ul>
  <li data-id="1"><a href="@Url.Action("View", "People", new { id = 1})">...</a></li>
  <li data-id="2"><a href="@Url.Action("View", "People", new { id = 2})">...</a></li>
  <li data-id="3"><a href="@Url.Action("View", "People", new { id = 3})">...</a></li>
</ul>
```

The data-id property might then be obsolete. If you still need the id client-side I suggest using a hidden field.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the code below,

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("View", "People", new { id = $(this).attr("data-id") })';
```